# Azure app service URL not secure

Tags: azure

My azure app service shows secure sometimes and sometimes it shows as not secure to browse. I have uploaded CA issued SSL certificate to acquire a dedicated inbound IP. Not sure but seems when load increases the app service shows as unsafe to browse. Also there are performance issues and responds slowly.please suggest on how to show it as secure always and have better performance.

Comment: Please share additional information such as what is exact unsafe error that you are getting? Maybe a screenshot and error message

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you have a load balancer configured within Azure and the second node that is receiving connections is not assigned your ssl certificate. I'm guessing the reason you are only seeing the issue under heavy load is because your load balance is using a weighted connection algorithm to route new connections to either a newly created or already provisioned node when the first node has reached a high enough active connection count.

If this is your issue, and you discover that you have an internal load balancer (ILB), here is Microsoft's guide to [Using an Internal Load Balancer with an App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-environment-with-internal-load-balancer).

> 1. Go to ASE UI after ASE is created ASE -> Settings -> ILB
>      Certificates
> 2. Set ILB certificate by selecting certificate pfx file and provide
>      password. This step takes a little while to process and the message
>      that a scaling operation is in progress will be shown.
> 3. Get the ILB address for your ASE (ASE -> Properties -> Virtual IP
>      Address)
> 4. Create a web app in ASE after creation
> 5. Create a VM if you don't have one in that VNET (Not in the same
>      subnet as the ASE or things break)
> 6. Set DNS for your subdomain. You can use a wildcard with your
>      subdomain in your DNS or if you want to do some simple tests, edit
>      the hosts file on your VM to set web app name to VIP IP address. If
>      your ASE had the subdomain name .ilbase.com and you made the web app
>      mytestapp so that it would be addressed at mytestapp.ilbase.com then
>      set that in your hosts file. (On Windows the hosts file is at
>      C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\ )
> 7. Use a browser on that VM and go to http://mytestapp.ilbase.com (or
>      whatever your web app name is with your subdomain)
> 8. Use a browser on that VM and go to https://mytestapp.ilbase.com You
>      will have to accept the lack of security if using a self-signed
>      certificate.

Comment: PrestonM will scaling out help?

Comment: @shaguftasyed I don't think scaling out will help. You will either have to replace the second node with a different one with an ssl cert, or assign an ssl cert to the second node.

Comment: while setting up ASE, if I configure VNET's VIP type to internal, will that be a dedicated IP?